# Should i use a trigger or Behaviors for this?

Tags: silverlight, xaml, silverlight-4.0, silverlight-toolkit

I have an abstract object called Applicant and two different types of objects that inherit from Applicant called Business and Individual.  So I have three classes that look like this:

```
public abstract class Applicant
{
...
}

public class Individual : Applicant
{
  ...
}

public class Business : Applicant
{
  ...
}
```

Now in the DataGrid I want to show all the details of Applicant object. When you choose a row I want to show details of either the business or individual as a internal grid.  Something like this

```
<DataGrid>
     <DataGrid.Columns>
          <!--Show different columns -->
     </DataGrid.Columns>
     <DataGrid.RowDetailsTemplate>
         <!--Show if Individual -->
         <DataGrid>
              <DataGrid.Columns>
                <DataGridTextColumn Header="First Name" ... />
                <DataGridTextColumn Header="Last Name" ... />
              </DataGrid.Columns>
          </DataGrid>
          <!--Show if business -->
          <DataGrid>
              <DataGrid.Columns>
                <DataGridTextColumn Header="Business Name" ... />
                <DataGridTextColumn Header="Tax id" ... />
              </DataGrid.Columns>
          </DataGrid>
     </DataGrid.RowDetailsTemplate>
</DataGrid>
```

Now I'm not sure if I need to use a Triggers or Behaviors to accomplish this?  Thanks for everyones help!  FYI I'm using Silverlight 4.0 with Prism.

Answer (score 0):

I'd user use neither:

- Have two views (grids) - one renders Individual details, another renders Business details.
- Define a ContentControl inside of RowDetailsTemplate and make it a region.
- Then handle SelectedApplicant change in your ViewModel for the main grid so that it would activate the proper view in the region depending on the type of selected applicant.

Comment: That sounds like a good idea.  Where would I put SelectedApplicantevent because right now I have a collection of applicants like this ObservableCollection<Applicant>?  Maybe I could even use LoadingRowDetails instead?

Comment: If you are in viewmodel world, then you wouldn't have an event - you'd bind SelectedItem of the grid to CurrentApplication property in your viewmodel. Thus when selection changed set method on the property would be automatically called.

Comment: I added this:
<sdk:DataGrid.RowDetailsTemplate><DataTemplate><ContentControl regions:RegionManager.RegionName="myRegion" /></DataTemplate></sdk:DataGrid.RowDetailsTemplate>
and I'm listening on event SelectionChanged and calling
var region = _regionManager.Regions["SearchesContainerRegion"];
but get exception
"The region manager does not contain the myRegion region."

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you need neither behaviours nor triggers but databinding. There is a great simple intro what databinding is in msdn [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc278072%28VS.95%29.aspx).

The thing that is unique in your cituation is that you don't have one but two different `DataTemplates` for your datagrid and you need to change them on the fly. I found a blogpost and a silverlight.net forum thread about that subject: [Changing Data-Templates at run-time from the VM](http://silverscratch.blogspot.com/2010/04/changing-data-templates-at-run-time.html) and [forum](http://forums.silverlight.net/forums/p/110737/250094.aspx).

First one uses some pretty simple codebehind logic and the one in the forum does the same thing using an `IValueConverter`.